# Regular expression for _ and #

Tags: regex

I need expression like

1. Accept  only 6 character
2. Numeric  and alpha numeric allow like (ABCDEF or 123456)
3. _  (allow only at 2 and 3 Position) and only 2 underscore allow.  Like(1__456)
4. #  (allow only at 3 and 4 Position) and only 2 hashes  allow. Like (12##56)
5. Both _ and # will not come at the same time. Like (1_##45 not  allowed)

Comment: (Also, honestly, this isn't really a good problem for a regex. Try a nice series of rule tests (or a series of regexes) instead.)

Answer (score 0):

There may be a cleaner way to do this, but this is working for me:

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9]{6})|([a-zA-Z0-9]\_{2}[a-zA-Z0-9]{3})|([a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\#{2}[a-zA-Z0-9]{2})$
```

Answer (score 0):

The following monster regex should do the trick:-

```
^([0-9A-Z][_0-9A-Z]{2}[0-9A-Z]{3})$|([0-9A-Z]{2}[#0-9A-Z]{2}[0-9A-Z]{2})$
```